# can i safely use np.random.binomial with a list of probabilities

Tags: python, numpy

```
numpy.random.binomial(1, [.1, .5, .9])
```

seems to work.

However the docs say that the 2nd parameter p is a float not a list.

Am I safe to use this?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that [np.random.binomial's docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) says `p` is expected to be a float.
However, the function is [defined here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L3588). Notice that the code tests for `p` being a float first, and if not, tries to convert `p` into a NumPy array:

```
fp = PyFloat_AsDouble(p)
if not PyErr_Occurred():
    ...
    return discnp_array_sc(self.internal_state, rk_binomial, size, ln,
                           fp, self.lock)

PyErr_Clear()
...

op = <ndarray>PyArray_FROM_OTF(p, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_ALIGNED)
```

So the code clearly allows for the possibility that `p` may be array-like.